Cairo-Dock Super Key not working
I want to set the Shortkey for the Application Menu to the Super Key (Windows Key) in Cairo-Dock>Configure>Shortkeys>Application Menu
but it does not register the Super Key when I press is. :(
I am assuming that the Raspberry Pi OS won't let me use the Super Key for anything else.
